# different values i want to get from option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, select

I have an object Car with a price, a model and a brand. I want to show this in a select.

I have a select that looks something like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Ford Mustang 30000</option>
    <option>Alfa Romeo giuletta 25000</option>
</select>
```

What could I do so I can get the price of the selected option.
So when I select option I can get every detail of the option ( brand,model,price)

```
var brand = ...
var model = ...
var price = ...
```

I tried with JSONObject and override the toString()-method, but then I can't transform it back to a JSONObject..

Thank you for your help

Comment: What's the problem here?  What's `JSONObject`?

Comment: Just add another field to the car object - ID.  Give them each a unique ID and assign that as the option value.  Then you can do a lookup when an option is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the html5 `data-` attribute to store the information on the option itself, then use js to access it.

```
<select id="cars">
<option data-brand='Ford' data-model='Mustang' data-price='30000'>Ford Mustang 30000</option>
</select>
```

In the js

```
var $selected_car = $('#cars :selected'); 
var brand = $selected_car.data('brand');
var model = $selected_car.data('model');
var price = $selected_car.data('price');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using HTML5 you can use `data` attributes. For example:

```
<select>
    <option value="30000" data-brand="Ford" data-model="Mustang">Ford Mustang 30000</option>
    <option value="25000" data-brand="Alfa Romeo" data-model="Giulietta">Alfa Romeo giuletta 25000</option>
</select>
```

Then in code you can pick these up:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    var $option = $("option:selected", $select)

    var brand = $option.data("brand");
    var model = $option.data("model");
    var price = $select.val();

    // do your thing...
});
```

Comment: Rocket you can event do `$('select option:selected')`

Comment: @azizpunjani Indeed, there's many ways to skin this particular cat. I chose the way I did as I already had the `$select` variable cached for use later.

Comment: haha it turns out you can just do `$('select :selected')` Like you said there's many ways to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're NOT using html5, you could encode all that data in the value attribute of each option.

```
<option value="{'brand':'Ford','model':'Mustang','price':'$30,000'}">Ford Mustang</option>

$("select").change(function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    var $option = $("option:selected", $select)
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON($option.value);

    var brand = data.brand;
    var model = data.model;
    var price = data.price;

    // do your thing...
});
```